# やり場のない怒りを、一番愛してる人に向けてしまう、嫌な女をやらせて

Tags: meaning

> やり場のない怒りを、一番愛してる人に向けてしまう、嫌な女をやらせて

My translation:

> Anger without outlet pointed toward the person I loved most made me a hateful woman

I'm particularly interested in the second part (there are 3) of the sentence. As I see it 一番愛してる人 is unambiguously referring to a single person. 人 is one of the few words in Japanese that are always accompanied by a pluralizing suffix when referring to more than one person, and 一番 literally means "one most, best, number 1".

Was my translation accurate or did I miss something? Also, does it mean he/she loves that person more than anyone else?

Comment: コンテクストください。----

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> やり場のない怒りを、 一番愛してる人に向けてしまう、 嫌な女をやらせて

- やり場のない怒りを -- the direct object of the verb 向ける. "anger with no outlet; anger that [she] doesn't know how to deal with."
- 一番愛してる人に -- the indirect object of 向ける. You're right that 一番愛してる人 means "the person whom [she] loves most; the one that [she] loves more than anyone else".
- やり場のない怒りを一番愛している人に向けてしまう is a relative clause modifying 嫌な女.
- 嫌な女をやらせて -- やらせて is used as a command here. やらせる is the causative form of やる. やる means "act the role; pretend to be" (≂ 演じる). "Let me act the role of a hateful woman."

Without context I read it as "Let me act the role of (or, Let me pretend to be) a hateful woman, who directs her bottled-up anger toward someone she loves most."

Comment: 2 questions to make sure (this is what interests me most): when yo say "towards someone she loves most": 1) That someone unambiguously refers to on single person and 2) she loves that person more than anyone else (not just very much). In this sentence it would be she loves that person the most (more than anyone else).

Comment: My previous questions refer to to the sentence as a whole. I would like to know if your change from "the one that I love more than anyone else" to "someone she loves most" in your final translation means it's different or it still means more than anyone else. Also to confirm that it unambiguously refers to one single person, not several people.

Comment: @Thebest 1) Yes, when you say 一番愛してる人, it unambiguously refers to one single person, not several people. 2) It's not different. 一番愛してる人 literally means "the person (someone) loves the most", and can be rephrased as "the person (someone) loves more than anyone else." (It means she loves that person more than she loves anybody else, not that she loves that person more than anybody else loves that person.)

Comment: One last question. In your final translation why did you change "the person" to "someone" and "the most" to "most"? You could have said "the person she loves the most" in your final translation as well?

Comment: @Thebest My English is not good enough to see the difference between "_the person_ I love" and "_someone_ I love", or "love _most_ " and "love _the most_", but the original Japanese sentence can be translated either way.

Comment: It's the same. As you said before "it means she loves that person more than she loves anybody else, not that she loves that person more than anybody else loves that person". Thank you for everything!

Comment: Last time to reassure myself. Forget about the english translation. The original japanese sentence (the whole sentence) is saying she loves that person more than anyone else (however you phrase that in english). Is this correct?

Comment: @Thebest Yes, in Japanese, 「一番愛している」 practically and logically means the same thing as 「誰よりも愛している」(*lit:* love more than anyone else).

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very  much for everything XD